# Having trouble manipulating bits with C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm having trouble figuring out how manipulting bits work with C. Was wondering if someone could clear up something for me.

These are the functions I have for set/get/clear bit

```
unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n)   
{ 
    (c & (1<<n)) >> c;
    return c;
}

unsigned char setBit(unsigned char c, int n)   
{ 
    c = c |(1<<n);
    return c;
}

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char c, int n) 
{ 
    c = c & (~1<<n);
    return c;
}
```

and let's say I have an `unsigned char test = 3`
in binary, 3 is 0000 0011

So if I were to do `printf("THIS IS THE VALUE AT BIT 0 = %hhu \n", getBit(test, 0));`
I would think it would return back `1`, but instead it returns the `test` value, which is 3.

I was wondering if I'm doing something wrong, my get/set/clear functions seem to be correct, am I not using the functions correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: At what point does `getBit` change the value of `c`?

Comment: And why does it shift by `c` instead of some function of `n`?

Comment: getBit isn't suppose to change the value of c, it's suppose to find the bit value of c, at the n'th position.

Comment: But if it doesn't change `c`, it will just return the value passed for `c` instead of the bit in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(c & (1<<n)) >> c
```

is an expression which does not *change* `c` at all. It's about as useful as the statement:

```
42;
```

You need to *change* `c` if you want to return it, with something akin to:

```
c = (c & (1<<n)) >> c;
```

or the simpler:

```
c = (c >> 1) & 1;
```

You already do that just fine with `setBit` and `clearBit`, you just need to adapt `getBit` the same way.

In addition, your `clearBit` will not work as is since the order of operations is wrong. The `<<` operator shifts in *zero* bits on the right hand side so `(~1<<4)` is actually binary `11100000` rather than `11101111`. Instead you need to ensure the shift is done *before* the bit inversion:

```
c = c & ~(1 << n);
```

---

And, since I take the minimalist approach to code, I'd probably ditch the "change `c` and return it" strategy for something simpler:

```
unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
    return (c >> n) & 1;
}

unsigned char setBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
    return c | (1 << n);
}

unsigned char clearBit(unsigned char c, int n) {
    return c & ~(1 << n);
}
```

And remember that you're *returning* the changed value for `setBit` and `clearBit`, so you have to assign it with something like:

```
unsigned char xyzzy = 0;
xyzzy = setBit (xyzzy, 3);
```

Comment: Since *42* is the answer to everything it would follow that the program would do the right thing after that statement is encountered. Unfortunately most compilers will optimize it away not realizing that `42;` has side effects ;-) .

Comment: Thank you for fixing the functions for me! I was wondering how I would use the clearBit and setBit functions properly. Would I have to do getBit(test, 0) = clearBit(test, 0), or would I be able to just declare clearBit(test, 0);


I'm trying both ways, but the values still seem to stay at 1.

Comment: nevermind! It worked after doign `key = clearBit(key, 0);` I'm guessing that's the right way to do it.

Comment: @johnnyboyyy, yes, I'd just added the usage down the bottom but you nutted it out anyway. I'll leave it there regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Make it simply by shifting the bit you want to the 1st position:

```
unsigned char getBit(unsigned char c, int n)   
{ 
    return  (c >> n) & 1;
}
```